# Accessing Facebook Events

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get all events from a facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314341/how-to-get-all-events-from-a-facebook-page)

I am working on a windows phone application and I need access to Facebook events.
I have found the Facebook C# SDK but there is nothing about accessing the events.
I am not asking for code, I am just asking how I can do this ?
Can I do this without FB user authorization ? Because I want to list the events that are in that location (for example city). The location is determined by a GPS or WI-Fi. Any idea ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook C# SDK does not give you direct access to objects inside Facebook, but rather opens a communication line with the Facebook API.

You'll need to query the Facebook API in order to obtain information regarding events. This won't be possible without your user authorizing your app.

See more here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks a lot jbkkd! I will inform you about my progress.